# Evaluating this in Assembly (A % B) % (C % D)

Tags: assembly, x86, expression, division

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDELIB Irvine32.lib
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib
INCLUDELIB user32.lib

.data
    A  SBYTE 10d ; A is an 8-bit signed integer
    B  SBYTE 2d  ; B is an 8-bit signed integer
    cc SBYTE 20d ; C is an 8-bit signed integer
    D  SBYTE 5d  ; D is an 8-bit signed integer

.code
main PROC
    mov EAX, 0
    mov EDX, 0

    mov al, A  ; Load A into AL register
    
    imul B
    movsx bx, cc
    imul bx
    movsx bx, D
    imul bx

    call DumpRegs ;
 
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

I have this code and I want to modify it to print output for this  (A % B) % (C % D) but when I use `idiv` the code doesn't give any outputs.

Comment: Show the code with `idiv`, and explain what you mean by *doesn't give any output*, since I presume `DumpRegs` always outputs the registers no matter what they contain.

Comment: What output do you expect for `0%0`?

Comment: Another issue is if you want remainder, where remainder has same sign as dividend, or modulo where modulo has same sign as divisor. The `idiv` instruction returns a remainder.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mov al, A  ; Load A into AL register
> imul B
> movsx bx, cc
> imul bx
> movsx bx, D
> imul bx
> ```

This code calculates `A * B * cc * D`, simply multiplying the 4 numbers.

> but when I use `idiv` the code doesn't give any outputs.

You can't just substitute that instruction: `imul` outputs to AH / DX / EDX / RDX, where `idiv` inputs from AH / DX / EDX / RDX. You need to develop a new solution from scratch.

The solution for this task must not only use the division instruction, but also respect the algebraic order of things as indicated by the parenthesis.
Although the 4 variables were defined as *signed* integers, I see their values are all positive numbers. Therefore I will present a solution that uses the `div` instruction. I would hate to take the fun away, so I will leave the signed version of this up to you...

```
.data
    A  BYTE 10
    B  BYTE 2
    C  BYTE 20
    D  BYTE 5

.code
main PROC
    ; (C % D)
    movzx ebx, D
    test  bl, bl
    jz    ERROR     ; #DE can't divide by zero
    movzx eax, C
    xor   edx, edx
    div   ebx       ; EDX:EAX / EBX --> EDX is remainder
    test  edx, edx
    jz    ERROR     ; #DE can't divide by zero          (*)
    mov   ecx, edx
    
    ; (A % B)
    movzx ebx, B
    test  bl, bl
    jz    ERROR     ; #DE can't divide by zero
    movzx eax, A
    xor   edx, edx
    div   ebx       ; EDX:EAX / EBX --> EDX is remainder
    
    ; (A % B) % (C % D)
    mov   eax, edx
    xor   edx, edx
    div   ecx       ; EDX:EAX / ECX --> EDX is remainder
    
    ; Result is in EDX
```

With the current data set, the program errors out at the asterisk!